# How to use Twilio StatusCallback in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio-php

I have looked through all documentation and I cannot find a way to receive my StatusCallback from my Codeigniter app and need some help please. I have an app that sends out an sms to a client. I just need Twilio to return the status as it updates. My app will get the status as soon as it queues up but I can't get a response with any updates. Thanks in advance for any help.

Controller:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($this->AccountSid, $this->AuthToken);
$client->account->messages->sendMessage($from, $to, $body_message, NULL, array("StatusCallback" => $callbackurl));
```

Like I said, everything is working great except the StatusCallback. I searched on this topic and I just see a bunch of confusion and not many people getting it to work. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks!!

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Can you give us a bit more detail on what you've tried so far and whats not worked with those attempts?  It looks like you are using the API correctly.  Can you open the value of $callbackurl in a browser?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My $callbackurl is just the index page of my app. When I open that up in a browser I get my normal app page but I have nothing in my $_REQUEST or $_GET indicating that anything is happening.  Perhaps I just don't know the proper way to get the twilio values from my $callbackurl?